# Print complex numbers in polar form (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I want to show a complex matrix in polar form in Matlab, however all the complex numbers are printed in rectangular form, for example:

```
\>> sqrt(2)*[1-1i 1+1i; 1i -1]

ans =

   1.4142 - 1.4142i   1.4142 + 1.4142i
        0 + 1.4142i  -1.4142
```

Is there a way to print complex numbers in polar form? Something like this:

```
\>> sqrt(2)*[1-1i 1+1i; 1i -1]

ans =

   2.0000 <-45.0000°   2.0000 < 45.0000°
   1.4142 < 90.0000°   1.4142 <180.0000°
```

It can be a function also, I just want to know if something like this has already been made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on what Luis Mendo was talking about, I don't believe there is a utility in MATLAB that prints out a complex number in polar form.  However, we can use `abs` and `angle` to our advantage as these determine the magnitude and phase of a complex number.  With these, we can define an auxiliary function that helps print out the magnitude and phase of a complex number in polar form.  Something like this:

```
function out = polarPrint(A)
    absA = abs(A);
    phaseA = angle(A)*180/pi;
    out = arrayfun(@(x, y) sprintf('%f < %f', x, y), absA, phaseA, 'uni', 0);
```

Place this in a file called `polarPrint.m` so that you can call this in MATLAB whenever you need it.  The first and second lines of code determine the magnitude and phase of a complex number stored in `absA` and `phaseA` respectively from an input matrix `A` that is numeric.  If you want it in degrees, you simply multiply by `180 / pi`.  The third line is the most magical.  We simply go through each element in `absA` and `phaseA`, print each to a string using [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) with a `<` separated between the two numbers and this string is placed in a cell array.  [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) goes through every element in an array and applies a function to this element.  In this case, I will let `arrayfun` go through two arrays simultaneously, which will be the magnitude and phase of each number in `A`.  As such, I'm going to use `absA` and `phaseA` as inputs into this function I want to apply to each of these elements.  The `uni = 0` flag means that the output is not numeric but it will be a cell array of non-numeric outputs (i.e. strings in our case).

`out` will contain a cell array of strings that is the same size as `A` that you can print out and examine yourself.

Using Luis Mendo's example, we get:

```
>> A = sqrt(2)*[1-1i 1+1i; 1i -1];       
>> out = polarPrint(A)

out = 

    '2.000000 < -45.000000'    '2.000000 < 45.000000' 
    '1.414214 < 90.000000'     '1.414214 < 180.000000'
```

Comment: You could use `arrayfun(@(x,y) sprintf('%f < %f',x,y), abs(A), angle(A)*180/pi, 'uni', 0)` to get away without reshaping.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Ah! I always forget about `arrayfun` taking in > 1 argument.  I'll revise my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng - You the real MVP. Thanks, Really.

Comment: @DanielTurizo - ahahah I'm just a poser.  The real heroes are people like Luis Mendo, Divakar, Amro, chappjc, etc.  A lot of what I learned from MATLAB was from them.  Still, thanks for the sentiment :)

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for your comments :-) Pity that Matlab's command window doesn't seem to support the [angle character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2220/index.htm)

Answer (score 3):

There are the following functions:

- [`abs`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html): gives complex magnitude;
- [`angle`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html): gives phase angle, in radians. You can convert to degrees with [`radtodeg`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/radtodeg.html) or `rad2deg` (or just multiplying by `180/pi`):

Example:

```
> A = [ sqrt(2)*[1-1i 1+1i; 1i -1]];

>> abs(A)
ans =
    2.0000    2.0000
    1.4142    1.4142

>> radtodeg(angle(A))
ans =
   -45    45
    90   180
```

Comment: FYI, both `radtodeg` and `rad2deg` appear to be in the Mapping toolbox (there's also `convert2deg` in the Signal Processing toolbox) and so may not be available to all users. However both are of course nothing more than `angleInDegrees = (180/pi) * angleInRadians;` and could easily be replaced by a simple anonymous function. It's silly that there isn't a native non-toolbox function even if this is simple math.